# Converting a text file to a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Total noob to SQL, so beware.

I have a text file that I would like to make a database out of.  After that is completed, I would like to execute some simple SQL statements I wrote.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and it won't let me do anything unless I connect to a database.  I don't really have server where my database is stored, so is there a way to just create a database without necessarily connecting to it?

Or is there a way to convert my text file to a database, then get Management Studio to connect it locally?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you want to do? You mention "some simple SQL statements"... like what?

Comment: Without seeing the contents of your text file, I would tend to think that your file correlates more to a table than a database.  There are likely numerous options for you, but there are too many unknowns.  Any additional info you could provide would help.

Answer (score 0):

Server Management Studio is just a GUI that interacts with a database (SQL Server engine).
If you don't have a SQL Server installed locally (either Express or Developer or any of the more cost intesive ones) and you don't have any Server you can connect to where a SQL Server instance is installed, SSMS won't help you at all.

What do you mean by  "is there a way to just create a database without necessarily connecting to it?"

If you're able to create a database then you've got access to a SQL Server instance.

The general approach to make a database out of a text file is weird....

A database consists (among many other items) of several tables. How would you be able to store several (structured) tables in a single text file?

I strongly recommend to rethink what you're trying to do and do some basic research on RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

There's a SQL Server Import/Export wizard which can take various delimited files and can insert the data into a new or existing table.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178430.aspx